# Can't connect to Office 365 in Android

Tags: android, azure, authentication, office365

First of all, sorry for my English.

Well, I'm trying to log in to microsoft account with android, I use the github example that provide Microsoft (https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Android-Connect). I follow all the steps but in the end when I try to connect with my account the server throws an exception.

Error:
`SERVER_ERROR:2016-01-28 11:05:38-cc63876c-3c31-48aa-9847-513381e09296-IOException:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token ver:1.1.7`

I can't find any information about this problem. Someone knows what is happening?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ricalo, in this case, the IOException is throwing because the email account what I'm using is a MSA account (Managed Service Accounts) instead of an Office 365 account.

Answer (score 0):

Aitor.

The **IOException** could be caused by a number of situations.

Let's see if we can come up with more information:

- Were you able to see the login page and provide credentials?
- What happens if you open a browser in your device and go to
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
- Can you share some of the logs before and after the error?